# I have buffer in WinMain which i need inside WndProc. How to pass pointer to it?

Tags: c, winapi, wm-paint

When i process WM_PAINT in WndProc, i need data from WinMain. In this case, pointer to char[], but the type of the data is irrelevent actually. The problem is, how to pass something from WinMain to WndProc.

To make it global is not preferable, but if i need to, i will live with it.
I really don't want to attach it to the extra window memory.
I can process WM_PAINT in WinMain directly, but i don't know if Windows ever send this message instead of posting it in the queue, if it does, then what?

Comment: What's wrong with storing the data inside the window? There are many different ways to do that - `WNDCLASS::cbWndExtra`, `GWL_USERDATA`, `SetProp()`, `SetWindowSubclass()`, etc. In any case, `WM_PAINT` is a low-priority synthesized message, the message queue generates it when there are no other messages waiting. However, that doesn't stop other code/libraries from sending `WM_PAINT` directly. Like most messages, `WM_PAINT` is best handled in the `WinProc` so it doesn't matter where it originates from.

Comment: If you don't wan't to use extra window memory, maybe this will work for you. When you call CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx (from WinMain), pass the address of the data in the lpParam argument (in your case the data is already a pointer, so you can just pass that), then process the WM_CREATE message, the pointer will be in the lpCreateParams member of the CREATE_STRUCT (i.e. the lparam argument of the WM_CREATE message). You can then assign the pointer to a static local variable in your window procedure.

Comment: @Stuart that approach is only viable if there is only ever 1 instance of the window alive at a time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point, I thought of some more obvious reasons why the approach wouldn't work, but that didn't occur to me. I did say "maybe this will work for you".

Comment: Reserving and using per-window memory to store per-window data is the standard solution. If that doesn't work for you you will need to explain your additional constraints that prevent you from using the standard solution.